# Prevent form from rescaling itself - DPI awareness

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 the feature of being "DPI Aware" has been added. When populating a datatable via this command:

```
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt) <---- This is the line where the rescaling occurs
```

At the line above, the form will rescale itself to a smaller size to match what the monitor has set for it's scale property in Windows. How do I prevent this? I do not want the form to rescale and change size but rather just stay as it was.

Note: I am aware you can restart Visual Studio in a "DPI unaware" state but even in this state the above problem happens when the application is ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to solve this behavior:

1. In Visual Studio, right click on your project > `Add` > `New Item..`
2. Select `Application.Manifest File` from the options. Keep the default name of `app.manifest`. Click `Add`. This will generate a manifest for your project. (Note: By default your application does **not** include the manifest file.
3. Open the newly created manifest file. Everything should already be populated. Uncomment this section (by removing the `<!--` before and `-->` after):

`<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">false</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
    </application>`

4. Save manifest file and compile. Your forms will no longer rescale.

**Complete manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
 <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
<security>
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <!-- UAC Manifest Options
         If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
         requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

        Specifying requestedExecutionLevel element will disable file and registry virtualization. 
        Remove this element if your application requires this virtualization for backwards
        compatibility.
    -->
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
</trustInfo>

<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
<application>
  <!-- A list of the Windows versions that this application has been tested on
       and is designed to work with. Uncomment the appropriate elements
       and Windows will automatically select the most compatible environment. -->

  <!-- Windows Vista -->
  <!--<supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}" />-->

  <!-- Windows 7 -->
  <!--<supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" />-->

  <!-- Windows 8 -->
  <!--<supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}" />-->

  <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
  <!--<supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}" />-->

  <!-- Windows 10 -->
  <!--<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />-->

</application>
</compatibility>

<!-- Indicates that the application is DPI-aware and will not be automatically scaled by Windows at higher
   DPIs. Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications are automatically DPI-aware and do not need 
   to opt in. Windows Forms applications targeting .NET Framework 4.6 that opt into this setting, should 
   also set the 'EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing' setting to 'true' in their app.config. -->

<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
<windowsSettings>
  <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">false</dpiAware>
</windowsSettings>
</application>


<!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
<!--
<dependency>
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity
      type="win32"
      name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
      version="6.0.0.0"
      processorArchitecture="*"
      publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
      language="*"
    />
</dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
-->

</assembly>
```